# EF 5.0 bug with explicit loading?

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I have two entities, SalesRep and Customer. 
My Customer has an OEM SalesRep and a Direct SalesRep, thus two foreign keys like so:

```
public int OemRepId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("OemRepId")]
public SalesRep OemRep { get; set; }

public int DirectRepId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("DirectRepId")]
public SalesRep DirectRep { get; set; }
```

In my context I have disabled lazy loading (and the properties are NOT virtual). I want to force explicit loading throughout the project. Here is how I disable LazyLoading in the context's constructor.

```
this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

Now, when I receive the customer property from the context, both the OemRep and the DirectRep are NULL which is correct.

I can then explicitly load the OemRep like so:

```
//I already have my CurrentCustomer entity loaded with its OemRep and DirectRep both NULL
_ctx.Entry(currentCustomer).Reference(c => c.OemRep).Load();
```

If I break in code right after this line, I see the OemRep reference property is now loaded. Here is the bug.

If the OemRepId and DirectRepId happen to be the same, the OemRep AND DirectRep reference properties ARE BOTH populated. If they happen to be different, I have to explicitly load them both like so:

```
_ctx.Entry(currentCustomer).Reference(c => c.OemRep).Load();
_ctx.Entry(currentCustomer).Reference(c => c.DirectRep).Load();
```

Why is the DirectRep populated when I hadn't explicitly loaded it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF tries it's best to populate all properties in the context with the data it has available.

It is smart enough to know that when it loads the SalesRep row with id `1764`, it can populate all properties of type `SalesRep` with that id as the foreign key.

In your case, it means that loading an `OemRep` may populate the `DirectRep` property if it references the same database row.

If the foreign keys reference different `SalesReps`, you have to load both explicitly.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I thought but I couldn't find any documentation stating so. I see EF is smart enough to do that, but where is it documented? Thanks.

Comment: I've never seen it documented, but EF's behaved that way since at least EF 4.0. I can't see the behaviour changing though, as so many people rely on it.